# reduceRight with an array of functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does this code do with the list of functions?

```
store = {};

mw = [f1, f2, f3];

ds = mw.map(function (fn) {
    return fn.bind(null, store);
});

ds2 = ds.reduceRight(function (dispatch, fn) {
    return fn.bind(null, dispatch);
});
```

it is combining it somehow, but I don't understand the goal. What are requirements for `f*` functions?

Comment: In `ds` an empty object is binded to the functions and in `ds2` I think that f3 is being binded to f2 and f2 to f1. So I would say that the requirements for the functions are that they take as arguments an object and a function. f3 can actually take just an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original functions are curried twice with an argument value: once with `store`, and the second time with a callback function `dispatch`, which through `reduceRight` is a function that refers to the next curried function in the array.

So `f*` should be functions that take two arguments: the object that plays a role (for anything you want), and the callback function to be called next. The exception to this rule is the *last* function: it doesn't get a second argument.

Here is an example for those functions:

```js
function f1(store, dispatch) {
    store["f1"] = "I";
    return dispatch();
}
function f2(store, dispatch) {
    store["f2"] = "was";
    return dispatch();
}
function f3(store) {
    store["f3"] = "here";
    return store;
}

var store = {};
var mw = [f1, f2, f3];
var ds = mw.map(function (fn) {
    return fn.bind(null, store);
});
var ds2 = ds.reduceRight(function (dispatch, fn) {
    return fn.bind(null, dispatch);
});
// ds2 is a function, that chains all given functions together 
//   through the callback system that they implement:
console.log(ds2());
```

Comment: If `f*` are two argument functions, then were is second argument bound? `nulls` stands for `this` binding...

Comment: The first argument of `bind` determines the `this` value, which only is relevant the *first* time. The other arguments of `bind` apply to the arguments that are not bound yet. This may seem a bit inconsistent, as the first argument of `bind` is dealt with in a different way, but yes, it is like that.

Comment: Sorry don't understand :(   So where is second argument bound? `fn.bind(null, dispatch)` ? Then what does `null` stands for here?

Comment: In this case `fn` is not the original function, but a function with *one* argument. This is because `fn` was created from the original `f*` function, by providing a value for its `this` and its first argument. So picture `fn` as `(dispatch) => f1.bind(null, store)`. With this second call of `bind`, the `null` is ignored (this argument has no effect), and `dispatch` serves to bind the *only* argument that `fn` takes.

Comment: ah, true, now I see

Comment: To correct my above comment: picture `fn` as `(dispatch) => f1.bind(null, store)(dispatch)`